# set selected value in jquery multiselect dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a scenario that I have to set the multiple values as selected in the multi-select dropdown as shown in below screenshot.

Following is my model and I have ExcursionList as the type of string List there.

```
 public class HotelInfo
{
 public List<string> ExcursionList { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning my hotel information as a JSON result in the controller and retrieve that value in jquery as shown in below code.

```
function LoadHotelDetails(data) {
    if (data) {
        $.each(data.ResultList, function (index, value) {
            $("#hotelName").val(value.HotelName);
            $("#nights").val(value.Nights);

            // this console.log print ["* EARLY CHECK-IN", " * LATE CHECK-OUT", " *- REFUND -*"] value to console.
            console.log(value.ExcursionList);

            $("#excursion").val(value.ExcursionList);

            $('#excursion').multiselect('refresh');

}
```

As in console.log value, I am getting 3 selected value. But in my dropdown, It's selecting only one value as shown in the below screenshot.

I am really thankful if anybody can help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For the help. I was able to fix the issue using razor view engine and C#. Without using jquery.

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ExcursionList, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ExList), new { @class = "form-control", id = "excursion", multiple = "multiple" })
```

The above works perfectly by selecting the dropdown values correctly

Comment: Side note - the `ListBoxFor()` method already adds `multiple = "multiple"` - you do not need to add it again

Answer (score 0):

> Note:
>   val is use set value using value attribute of drop-down 
>   e.g

```
<select>
 <option value="1" > option 1  </option>
 <option value="2" > option 2  </option>
 </select>
```

In your case you need to set value using text().

```
$("#excursion").text(value.ExcursionList).multiselect('refresh');
```

Try this

```
var tempArr = [];

 function LoadHotelDetails(data) {
if (data) {
    $.each(data.ResultList, function (index, value) {
        $("#hotelName").val(value.HotelName);
        $("#nights").val(value.Nights);

        // this console.log print ["* EARLY CHECK-IN", " * LATE CHECK-OUT", " *- REFUND -*"] value to console.
        console.log(value.ExcursionList);
        tempArr.push(value.ExcursionList)
    }); //closing of each

        $("#excursion").text(tempArr).multiselect('refresh');
      //  $('#excursion').multiselect('refresh');
  tempArr = []; //empty temp array
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Asif, But its not working either. In my scenario I got one value selected. But in this scenario, no value is selected.